# mysqldump: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted while running database Backup

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

While running database backup running command in server (CloudFoundry) I am getting this error :

```
mysqldump: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted when dumping table `attac
hment` at row: 26
```

why its giving such an error? is it because mysql kills some process that takes too much time.. ? or because of any other reason?

Comment: Is it having a lot of data in the table? CF does kill query processes took more than 3 seconds. You might want to choose "none" for the tunnel command and launch a separate mysqldump with some tuning options to see whether it can pass.

Answer (score 1):

CF does kill query processes took more than 3 seconds. Try the following steps to see whether it can be worked out:

1) vmc tunnel service_name

2) choose "none" for the tunnel command

3) launch a separate mysqldump process with some tuning options like --where

See whether it can pass.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a ~140GB database, and got the same error.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.51, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

In my case, I wanted to move the DB to another server so I enabled these settings first in `/etc/my.cnf` to setup a replication process.

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
```

I restarted the server so the master would start logging for replication.
Then I added these settings to prevent the `Error 1317` timeout. specifically the read/write timeouts were previously too low for large table queries.

```
net_read_timeout=9999
net_write_timeout=9999
net_retry_count=999
```

Then I used this command to get the dump, leveraging the 'point in time'.
Since 'server 2' hasn't been started, it will dump everything.
After I turn replication on for server 2, it will pull any new records since this dump.
You can omit the `--master-data=2` if you're not doing replication.

`sudo mysqldump --compress --max-allowed-packet=1G --master-data=2 --single-transaction --databases ${dbname} -r ${backupname}`
It took about 4hrs to complete.

Here's my complete `/etc/my.cnf` for reference -

```
$ cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
bulk_insert_buffer_size=20971520
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=16777216
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
net_read_timeout=9999
net_write_timeout=9999
net_retry_count=999
```